# Get all instances of a registered open generic interface in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I would like to register an interface in StructureMap as open generic and being able to obtain instances of its implementations specifying a constraint:

```
interface ITestInterface<T> { }

class TestGenericClassOne<T> : ITestInterface<T> { }

class TestGenericClassTwo<T> : ITestInterface<T> { }

[...]

_container.Configure(expression => expression.Scan(scanner =>
{
    scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ITestInterface<>));
    scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ITestInterface<>));
}));

// Should return a TestGenericClassOne<int> and a TestGenericClassTwo<int>.
var actual = _container.GetAllInstances<ITestInterface<int>>().ToArray();
```

Is there any way to achieve this?